# Recursive function for reversing a number

Tags: c, recursion, static, reverse

The statement of my problem is this:

> Write a recursive function that takes a natural number as argument and returns the value of the number read backwards (with the decimal digits in opposite order):
>
> E.g : `f(3120) = 213`

I have solved the problem but I used `static` to store my reversed number as in the code below:

```
unsigned long f(unsigned long n){
    static long rev;
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else            
        {
            rev=rev*10+n%10;
            f(n/10);
        }
    return rev;         
}
```

but I would like to know if there is a way to solve this problem without using the `static` data type and still keeping only one parameter in the function.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Just remove the word `static` from your code and do calulations in loop:

```
unsigned long f(unsigned long n){
    long rev = 0;
    while(n != 0) {
        rev = rev*10 + n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but my function has to be recursive.

Answer (score 1):

You could put current result as an argument of your function:

```
int f(int x, int r = 0)
{
    if (x == 0) return r;
    return f(x / 10, r * 10 + x % 10);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `int f(int x, int r = 0)` would compile. BTW, The OP says "_still keeping only one parameter in the function._"

Comment: It would compile with int f(int x, int r) if you call the function with f(3120,0) but I need the function to have as parameter only the number that I want to reverse.